# What is the smallest prime $P>2$ with this property?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let P be a prime number and P=$m^{\text{th}}$ prime number. Here I'm interested in a prime P$>2$, such that P divides the concatenation of the first $(2m-1)$ prime numbers. Using my old laptop I've checked P up to $7919$ (i.e: up to the $1000^{\text{th}}$ prime number)without finding a solution. Can you find the smallest /some primes P$>2$ with such property ?

Comment: You are using *Mathematica* for this? Have you written code already?

Comment: No, I did it manually with my laptop.

Comment: You did it manually? Such effort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Fixed typo (Sahra B.) and used Divisible (J.M.):

Is this the operation you mean?

```
concatenate[a__] := ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString /@ a]]

f[m_] := concatenate[Prime[#] & /@ Range[1, 2 m - 1]]

f[#] & /@ Range[5]
```

> {2, 235, 235711, 2357111317, 23571113171923}

```
checkM[m_] := Divisible[f[m], Prime[m]]

Timing[Select[Range[2,2*10^6], checkM[#] &, 1]]
```

yields:

> {0.207871, {303}}

suggesting that the 303th prime satisfies the above check?

---

You can look at code and actual integers involved [ [here](https://gist.github.com/drjjmc/a9b9e20f28f3e4eaa7fbff76631369c7) ].

Comment: Might be better to use `Divisible[f[m], m]`.

Comment: More efficient & easier to read, or functionally different?

Comment: Well, taking GCDs needs less effort than performing an actual division for large enough integers.

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco, you mean the $303^{\text{th}}$ prime gives solution ?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo where I wasn't dividing by the $m$-thprime , rather dividing by $m$, fixed, and included J.M.'s suggestion

Comment: I used the MOD, it is very fast to give residues.

Comment: But you didn't find that the 303th prime ( 1999 ) satisfies your criteria?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding (misimplementing) the property you're looking for?

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco, I mean if a prime P=$m^{\text{th}}$ prime number, divides the concatenation of the first (2m-1) prime numbers, then P becomes a solution for this.

Comment: So, just to make sure: you are happy if the 303th prime: (1999) divides the concatenation (string join) of the first 605 primes.  a number that looks like    (2 3 ... 4447 4451)  (with no spaces)

Comment: Yes, 605th prime is 4451.

Comment: I must made  an error at some point at the concatenation :( (thanks John !)